# Can't push items into array from anonymous callback function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a javascript issue that's driving me completely insane.  I have a collection of data that I'm iterating over using the jQuery .each() method.  Inside the .each() callback function, I'm pushing data on the an array.  Here's the code.

```
var p = procedure_tool.all();
previousValue = -1;
var proceduresArray = [];
p.each(function(d, proceduresArray) {
proceduresArray.push(d.procedureID);
});
```

I've also tried making the proceduresArray global (no var in front), and then trying not to pass it through the anonymous function.

```
var p = procedure_tool.all();
previousValue = -1;
proceduresArray = [];
p.each(function(d) {
proceduresArray.push(d.procedureID);
})
```

The data does exist (alerts inside the callback display it fine).  Any ideas?  I feel like it's a scope issue, but I figure that globalizing the array would have fixed it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things,

1- You don't need to pass the proceduresArray to the anonymous function.
2- The anonymous function in .each() is passed 2 things. The first is the index of the element and the second is the element. I.e. `callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement)` http://http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

This should work just fine:

```
var p = procedure_tool.all();
previousValue = -1;
var proceduresArray = [];
p.each(function(i, d) {
proceduresArray.push(d.procedureID);
});
```

Another example:

```
var p = $('div');
var pArray = [];

p.each(function(i, el)
{
    pArray.push(el);
});

console.log(pArray);
```

Keep in mind the value can also be accessed using `this` within the anonymous function.

- Christian

Comment: While this didn't solve my problem directly, it did highlight another oversight.  I was using the .each() iterator (which is generally used for DOM elements) instead of jQuery.each() iterator which is meant to iterate over any object.