# Iterate over all ids in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to iterate over all spans in an iframe with ids that start with a string

```
var myString = "starts with this id";
var myArray = [];
  $('#ifr').ready(function(){
    $(this).contents().find('span[id^="myString"]').each(function(i, obj) {
      myArray.push($(this).text);
    });
  });
  console.log(myArray);
```

What am I doing wrong?  At one point I got it to work, but I don't know what I did to mess it up...

Comment: Does your iFrame have an id of ifr ?

Comment: where is your iframe code

Comment: Are the spans actually inside the iframe, or are they outside like you posted in your question?

Comment: Only when I enter the code into inspect element and select the <iframe> to run the code does it work.  And yes, there is a separate html doc inside the iframe with these spans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. `myArray` is defined *outside* of the `.ready()` function. Simply move it inside the `.ready()` function and it'll work. See [Can't push items into array from anonymous callback function in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394758/cant-push-items-into-array-from-anonymous-callback-function-in-javascript) for more information on this.
2. You need to use `.text()` instead of `.text` to get the text of `$(this)`. (The text is gotten using a function, not an attribute).
3. You need to wait for the iframe to load with `.load()` instead of `.ready()`

So, with all those fixed, here's what your code should look like:

JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ptifrmtgtframe').load(function() {
    var myArray = [];
    $(this).contents().find('span[id^="MTG_INSTR$"]').each(function(i, obj) {
      myArray.push($(this).text());
    });
    console.log(myArray);
  });
});
```

HTML:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="ptifrmtgtframe" name="TargetContent" title="Main Content" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" onload="ptrc.onLoadTC()" src="https://www.lionpath.psu.edu/psc/CSPRD/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/SA_LEARNER_SERVICES.CLASS_SEARCH.GBL?pslnkid=PE_S201607061454417104632592&amp;PortalActualURL=https%3a%2f%2fwww.lionpath.psu.edu%2fpsc%2fCSPRD%2fEMPLOYEE%2fHRMS%2fc%2fSA_LEARNER_SERVICES.CLASS_SEARCH.GBL%3fpslnkid%3dPE_S201607061454417104632592&amp;PortalContentURL=https%3a%2f%2fwww.lionpath.psu.edu%2fpsc%2fCSPRD%2fEMPLOYEE%2fHRMS%2fc%2fSA_LEARNER_SERVICES.CLASS_SEARCH.GBL%3fpslnkid%3dPE_S201607061454417104632592&amp;PortalContentProvider=HRMS&amp;PortalCRefLabel=Class%20Search&amp;PortalRegistryName=EMPLOYEE&amp;PortalServletURI=https%3a%2f%2fwww.lionpath.psu.edu%2fpsp%2fCSPRD%2f&amp;PortalURI=https%3a%2f%2fwww.lionpath.psu.edu%2fpsc%2fCSPRD%2f&amp;PortalHostNode=HRMS&amp;NoCrumbs=yes&amp;PortalKeyStruct=yes" style="width: 626px; height: 593px;">
  <span class="PSLONGEDITBOX" id="MTG_INSTR$1">I want this text</span>
  <br>
  <span class="PSLONGEDITBOX" id="MTG_OTHER">But not this text</span>
</iframe>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me.  I tried your code, and I tried replacing '#ifr' with the actual name of the iframe, which is ptifrmtgtframe . (It sounds stupid to use #ifr but Im a newbie)  When I replace it with the iframe name, I get `[iframe#ptifrmtgtframe]
0
:
iframe#ptifrmtgtframe`

Comment: Sorry, it works.  But it only works when I choose the iframe in google inspect element and then type the code into the console.  I want to be able to run a content script with this code.  In inspect element, I can choose "top", "My Chrome Extension", "AdBlock", "<iframe>" and a few more

Comment: Also, in the iframe, the src=".. is not completely the same as the webpage domain.  It is the same until a certain point, but then there are extraneous text after.  Im not sure if this matters since the main part of the src is the same

Comment: Are the spans inside the iframe or are they actually outside the iframe?

Comment: They are inside.  THere is a whole separate html doc inside the iframe

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you try it again @defoification ?

Comment: It didn't work for me.  I got [document] which expands into a seemingly infinite expansion. I want the content when a user searches for a class here: [link](https://public.lionpath.psu.edu/psp/CSPRD/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/h/?tab=DEFAULT)

Comment: Do you want to get the content of the `GS_DELEGATE_WRK_EMAILID` and `GS_DELEGATE_WRK_PASSWORD` inputs? If not can you give me the id and tag name for the tags you want to get. @defoification

Comment: It's the span I included in my question.  When you search for a class, the content loaded will include these spans `<span class="PSLONGEDITBOX" id="MTG_INSTR$1">I want this text</span>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144895/discussion-between-david-and-defoification).